# Http Server with Lwip stack

Tags: http, stm32, stm32f4discovery, lwip

I want to do demo of echo server code by using Lwip stack ,
But right know i dont have the STM32 Nucleo/Discovery board with me .

Is it possible to execute the code without the board , means virtually

Comment: any comment will be helpful

Comment: There is [QEMU Arm project](https://xpack.github.io/qemu-arm/), you can try it to run some code or unit tests on target arch. But running full ethernet server might be a very different level